# Realm create() cannot parse JSON string to NSDate?

Tags: swift, realm

I am currently following this tutorial [here](https://realm.io/news/love-story-with-realm/)

It appears that Realm can automatically map JSON data to the object. However, it doesn't seem to play nicely with NSDate properties.

My JSON string looks like the following:

```
{
...
"created_at":"2015-12-08T11:59:45.315539Z"
...
}
```

My definition for `created_at`:

```
dynamic var created_at = NSDate()
```

The mapping and creation happens here:

```
   ...
   let data = response.result.value as! [[String: NSObject]]
   try! realm.write{
       for item in data{
        realm.create(MyModel.self, value: item, update:true)
    }
   }
```

That's the error I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '2015-12-08T11:59:45.315539Z' for property 'created_at''
```

Does that mean I need to manually map it for NSDate?

Comment: No, this is not possible at the moment, you will need to save it as a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. You cannot take a `String` containing a date and automatically map it to an `NSDate` property in Realm.

The easiest way to get around this, would be to deserialize your JSON data into a mutable dictionary, and then manually replace that specific `String` property with an `NSDate` value, generated from a `NSDateFormatter` object. Once that's done, you should be able to simply pass the dictionary to Realm to create the new `Object` in it.

This was previously discussed in a Realm GitHub issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/605